# html kable_styling not showing output in a for loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to use kable inside a for loop to generate a lot of tables in a HTML rmarkdown. I was looking for solutions and most of them are solved using the wrapper print around kable code. But when I want to generate html table outputs with kable_styling, this solution didn't work! For example:

```
table <- tibble(a = c(1:10),
            b = letters[1:10])


for(each in 1:2) {

print(table %>%
  kable())

  cat("<br>")

}
```

This generate two simple tables.

But when I try:

```
table <- tibble(a = c(1:10),
            b = letters[1:10])


for(each in 1:2) {

print(table %>%
  kable() %>%
    kable_styling("striped"))

  cat("<br>")

}
```

Nothing happens! And that's only for html outputs. With latex it's ok. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Add `htmltools::HTML()` to your pipe:

```
table %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>% 
  htmltools::HTML() %>% 
  print
```