# kable_styling inside a loop

Tags: r-markdown, kable

I've been trying to use kable to create a table inside a loop. I found out that I need to encase the kable inside a print statement and have cat("\n"). With that I was able to print the table inside the loop. However, the format looks bad. How do I make the table inside the loop to be formatted correctly?
How do I use kable_styling with print and kable inside a loop?

Here is my code

````
# function definition
test.kable <- function(filename){
rmarkdown::render(filename)
}

#test.rmd
```{r , echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
for (i in 1:2){
print(kable(head(iris)))
cat("\n")
}
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
kable_styling(kable(head(iris)),c("striped","bordered","responsive"))
```  

#main r markdown in which I call the function
```{r,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
test.kable("test.rmd")
```
````

Here is what it looks like in the html output. The first two iris tables doesn't have pretty format. How do I make them look like the last iris table?

[image: html output]

**EDIT regarding answer**

The accepted answer is useful as it tells me about css style that contains the table styling which I never pay attention. But if someone still wants to use kable_styling, I figured out you just need to do the following (credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54319044/3280489)):

````
```{r , echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
  for (i in 1:2){
  kable(head(iris)) %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>% 
  htmltools::HTML() %>% 
  print
  cat("\n")
  }
```
````

Here is what the two tables look like with `kable_styling`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to add a .CSS file, we can style the table, since it's output is an HTML table in your example.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "John Doe"
date: "18/11/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
---

#test.rmd
```{r , echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(kableExtra)
for (i in 1:2){
print(kable(head(iris)))
cat("\n")
}
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
kable_styling(kable(head(iris)),c("striped","bordered","responsive"))
```
````

Here is the .css file titled `styles.css` in the same directory as the .Rmd

```
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
table thead th { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
th, td { padding: 5px; }
thead, tfoot, tr:nth-child(even) { background: #eee; }
```

Which gives me the below output.

[image]

[Here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) is where I looked for help, it even has a section about HTML tables and loops using kable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I saw the link but was only looking at the loops using kable section but didn't read the beginning part so missed the css style. I was puzzled at why my table looks different.

Comment: Correct. Since the `kable_styling()` outputs a kable and the for loop outputs an html table